# Grid view not getting full view

Tags: android, gridview

I have grid view calendar in my application.But my grid view was not getting full view in my layout.only half of the page viewing when i am running the application.But i view in my graphical layout it take full view for grid calendar.here i include my xml part please any one help me thanks...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/calendarlayoutid"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridheader"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/header_background"
    >
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    >
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/gridprevious" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="&lt;&lt;" 
    android:clickable="true"
    />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gridtitle" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/previous"

    />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/title"
    >
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/gridnext" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text=">>"
    android:clickable="true"
    />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
        >
       <TextView 
           android:text="SUN"
           android:layout_width="0dip"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight=".08"/>
        <TextView 
           android:text="MON"
           android:layout_width="0dip"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight=".08"/>
         <TextView 
           android:text="TUE"
           android:layout_width="0dip"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight=".08"/>
          <TextView 
           android:text="WED"
           android:layout_width="0dip"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight=".08"/>
           <TextView 
           android:text="THU"
           android:layout_width="0dip"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight=".08"/>
            <TextView 
           android:text="FRI"
           android:layout_width="0dip"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight=".08"/>
             <TextView 
           android:text="SAT"
           android:layout_width="0dip"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight=".08"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridviewid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:columnWidth="90dp"    
    android:numColumns="7"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" 
    />

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

And my grid view have two textview rows.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/griddate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gridstatus"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gridview's height depends on the number of data to be filled in rows.

If you have data for 2 rows,you will see only 2 rows and if you have data for 5 rows,you will see only 5 rows.

Comment: In my calendar view i have 5 rows but not filling the page